# not found mod_alias module

Tags: apache2

running command `sudo service apache2 restart`

Get this error. How to solve it?

```
* Restarting web server apache2                                         [fail] 
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/alias.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_alias.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_alias.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Answer (score 1):

Run the following commands to install the missing file:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall apache2-bin
```